# Is it possible to host a website with Apache HTTP through a ZyXEL EQ-660R modem and a Netgear WGT624v3 wireless router?

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, http, port-forwarding, webserver

Essentially, I have a spare desktop computer I'd like to turn into a web server, but my modem and wireless router are very difficult to work with. I installed Apache HTTP and successfully hosted a test page which can be accessed anywhere on the LAN. However, I'm having trouble setting up the server to be accessed from my external IP address.

I was supplied with a ZyXEL EQ-660R DSL modem by my ISP (CenturyLink) and bought a Netgear WGT624v3 wireless router in which to connect my laptop and spare desktop.

ZyXEL's website is [no help](http://us.zyxel.com/Search.aspx?q=EQ-660R), and I don't think much of the problem is with the Netgear router. I've played with many settings and have tried to forward port 80 from the modem, but I've had no luck.

Could someone direct me toward a solution or recommendations for more promising hardware? Or should I admit defeat and explore other hobbies? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
                                             eth0
                                             192.168.1.10
                  1.2.3.4  192.168.1.1   +---[server]
                  eth0     eth1          |
--------[modem]------[router]------------+---[computer]
                                             192.168.1.101
                                             eth0
```

- you forward the ports at the router, not the modem, for most configurations
- forward port 80
- (optional) use service such as no-ip to set a domain name for your (presumably) dynamic IP address

Comment: I would add, though, that a lot of broadband modems these days have built-in router/firewall hardware - often you end up behind two levels of NAT, so you'll have to check both configurations. Best thing is probably to either turn off DHCP on the modem and forward port 80 there, if possible, or add your router IP to a DMZ.

Comment: Wow, thank you! This clears up A LOT of my misconceptions. Would it be wise to disable the firewall on my modem and leave the router's enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Another thing I might add is that you need to check if your ISP has granted you a PUBLIC IP address. I've been noticing more ISPs putting you behind their network, and you're getting issued a NON PUBLIC IP address (on your modem side) ..

easiest way to check this is 
go to IP2nation.com to check your PUBLIC IP 
then check your modem's WAN settings if you have the same IP.. if you do, then you're using a TRUE public IP .. if it's different, then you're out of luck.. You're issued an INTERNAL IP from within your ISP's network and if you need to get that port forwarded, you need to ask them to do it for you. This is actually my issue lately.

Good luck